# can client pay from his apple account to company from iphone application

Tags: iphone, xcode, e-commerce, payment

From My Previous question

[sending request to apple - from iphone custom application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415914/sending-request-to-apple-from-iphone-custom-application/1415927#1415927)

Here, I have added more specified my question.

Suppose my application has implemented followings.

Lets take an simple example

- I have developed an application, for mobile dealer.
- User can see ten mobile items on screen.
- Now, user selects two items.(mobiles)
- Now, User chooses check out option.
- in check out option, he will provide his apple account - id & password.

---

Above I have explained the process that should be implemented in my application.

Up to 4 stpes I can do programming.
But I have no idea about the last step.

1. Can user make payment through apple
   id - from iPhone?
2. What kind of steps do I/programmer
   have to follow?
3. What kind of accounts do
   I/programmer are required? (If
   any..)
4. What kind of certificates do
   I/programmer are required? (If
   any..)

Let's take an another example.

Suppose, Application if something like this,

- User can pay for bike (new order) through iPhone - apple id - password ?

**Edit :**
After a round - round question ...

Let's understand it in single line

**Does apple allow to use apple-ID for payment of items other than apple-store? Why ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StoreKit allows you to sell digital content, such as books, music, ect. and get it delivered right into the application. Payment happens via the iTunes account.

However, you cannot sell physical goods with this mechanism. You may want to consider other payment methods as mentioned by Amuck.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot sell your products through the Apple Store.  If you want to have an iPhone app that interfaces with your store you can do that, but you will have to provide your own store service.

To answer the edit to your question, Apple does not allow using an Apple ID to purchase products from other stores.  Instead you should use something like Paypal or Google Checkout.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the edited short-question:

> Does apple allow to use apple-ID for
>   payment of items other than
>   apple-store? Why ?

No, because they do not pose as a payment provider to third parties and I am pretty sure they never will.